# A property of trapezoids - Steiner's Theorem

Tags: euclidean-geometry

An important feature of trapezoids is that the midpoints of its bases, the intersection of its diagonals, and the intersection of the lines through its legs are collinear.

**Explanation for three of these points being collinear**

$\mathit{ABCD}$ is a trapezoid with bases $\overline{\mathit{AB}}$ and $\overline{\mathit{CD}}$. $M$ is the midpoint of $\overline{\mathit{AB}}$, $N$ is the midpoint of $\overline{\mathit{CD}}$, and $P$ is the intersection of the diagonals. $\angle\mathit{ABP} \cong \angle\mathit{CDP}$, and $\angle\mathit{BAP} \cong \angle\mathit{DCP}$. According to the Angle-Angle Similarity Theorem, $\triangle\mathit{PAB} \sim \triangle\mathit{PCD}$, and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{AB}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{CD}}\right\vert}
= \frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{BP}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{DP}}\right\vert}.
\end{equation*}
According to Apollonius's Theorem, medians $\overline{\mathit{PM}}$ and $\overline{\mathit{PN}}$ are such that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{PM}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{PN}}\right\vert}
= \frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{AB}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{CD}}\right\vert}
= \frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{BM}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{DN}}\right\vert}.
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{BM}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{DN}}\right\vert}
= \frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{BP}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{DP}}\right\vert}
= \frac{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{PM}}\right\vert}{\left\vert\overline{\mathit{PN}}\right\vert}
,
\end{equation*}
and, according to the Side-Side-Side Similarity Theorem, $\triangle\mathit{BMP} \sim \triangle\mathit{DNP}$. In partiuclar, $\angle\mathit{BPM} \cong \angle\mathit{DPN}$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\angle\mathit{MPN} &= \angle\mathit{BPM} + \angle\mathit{BPN} \\
&= \angle\mathit{BPM} + (180^\circ - \angle\mathit{DPN}) \\
&= \angle\mathit{BPM} + (180^\circ - \angle\mathit{BPM}) \\
&= 180^\circ.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $M$, $N$, and $P$ are collinear.

**Explanation for another three points being collinear**

If $Q$ is the intersection of the lines through the legs of the trapezoid, I would like an explanation for the collinearity of $M$, $N$, and $Q$ - an elementary explanation like the one showing the collinearity of $M$, $N$, and $P$.

Additionally, a careful explanation using a homothety would be much appreciated. I am starting to familiarize myself with the concept, and this would be a nice illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Consider line $QM$ and let $N'$ the point where it meets $CD$. Triangles $QDN'$ and $QAM$ are similar (or homothetic, if you prefer), hence $DN'/AM=QN'/QM$. Triangles $QCN'$ and $QBM$ are also homothetic, hence $CN'/BM=QN'/QM$. It follows that $DN'/AM=CN'/BM$, and from $AM=BM$ we have then: $DN'=CN'$, meaning that $N'=N$ and concluding the proof.